# Retrieve ID from recently inserted object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core with my own Unit-of-Work and generic repository pattern. I have a shadow property linking to entities that have no direct relationship in the db.
So I perform a UOW adding to two tables utilising the shadow property to get the ID from the first insert and placing it as a foreign key in the second without a constraint.
This all works fine and the newly inserted record in both tables correspond. So the primary key of the first table is placed in the second successfully, so I have my shadow relationship.

What I can't do is access this new ID field in C# code so I can then return it to the client.

Something like this..

```
      int entity1ID = _unitOfWork.entity1Repository.AddEntity1(entity1);
      //The value in entity1ID is -2147482647. This is used to map the shadow property.
      int entity2ID = _unitOfWork.entity2Repository.AddEntity2(entity2);
      int resultCount = await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

After this process is completed the everything works. I cannot get hold of the entity1ID field, if I check it then it still has the value -2147482647 inside it. Does anyone know of a decent solution to this problem.

Comment: Are both `Entity1.ID` and `Entity2.Entity1ID ` fields declared as shadow properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your `SaveChangesAsync()` is done, you can retrieve value of shadow property like that:

```
var entity1ID = dbContext.Entry(entity1).Property("ID").CurrentValue;
```